# Relationship between a matrix with specific eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is  a matrix for which its eigenvectors are only multiples of $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, then in general, can it be said that $A$ has repeated eigenvalues? Also, this matrix $A$ cannot be diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

Since your vector is $3\times 1$, the matrix is $3\times 3$. For it to be diagonalizable, there have to be three linearly independent eigenvectors. Since every eigenvector is a multiple of the single vector, the matrix cannot have three linearly independent eigenvectors, so your matrix is *definitely* not diagonalizable.

In addition, to every distinct eigenvalue there is at least one eigenvector, and eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. So your matrix can only have a single eigenvalue.

If you are working over a non-algebraically closed field (like the reals), it could mean that there is only one eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$, but that the other factor of the characteristic polynomial is irreducible quadratic. Otherwise, or over the complex numbers, the eigenvalue is repeated $3$ times.

For an example of the latter, consider the matrix
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccr}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
Over the reals, the only eigenvalue is $1$ (the characteristic polynomial is $-(x-1)(x^2+1)$), which is not repeated. All eigenvectors are multiples of $\mathbf{e}_1$.

So $A$ is definitely not diagonalizable, but it could have a single eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $1$. Otherwise, it has a single eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better understanding about eigenvectors, or start from eigenvectors and eigenvalues and then reason about the possible transformations they could belong to, eigencircles are a good tool.
They were introduced/defined in 2006 by Englefield and Farr.
Too bad eigencircles only work for 2x2 matrices.

Set $A=\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\\\end{matrix}\right]$, $A$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $\mathfrak{t}$

The reasoning about eigencircle starts from the observation that if you apply a linear transformation to 'a' vector $\vec(x)$, the 'displacement' from $\vec(x)$ to $\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})$ can always be described by a rotation and a change of length of the original vector.
**The eigencircle of a transformation $\mathfrak{t}$ or a matrix $A$ is the collection of all possible rotations and scalings 'produced' by the linear transformation.**

The eigencircle can be described both in a polar and Cartesian form, that is why I give the different formulations with ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{cart}$ and ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}$.

The eigencircle ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{cart}$ or ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}$ of a linear transformation $\mathfrak{t}$ is a circle defined by all possible tuples $(s,\theta)$

where
$\theta=\angle\left(\vec{x,}\mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)\right)$ is the angle between an original vector $\vec{x}$ and its image $\mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)$ and 
$s=\frac{\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|}{\|\vec{x}\|}$ is the scaling $s$ from the original length $\|\vec{x}\|$ to the final length $\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|$.

${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}=\left\{\left(\ s_{\vec{x}},\theta_{\vec{x}}\right)| \exists\vec{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\ and\ \mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}s_{\vec{x}}&0\\0&s_{\vec{x}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&-\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\+\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]=A\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$


${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}=\left\{\left(s_{\vec{x}},\theta_{\vec{x}}\right) |\ \exists \vec{x}\ such\ that\ s_{\vec{x}}=\frac{\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|}{\|\vec{x}\|} \ and\ \theta_{\vec{x}}=\angle(\vec{x},\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x}))\right\}$

${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{cart}=\left\{\left(\lambda,\mu\right)|\exists\vec{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]and\ \mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}\lambda &-\mu\\+\mu&\lambda\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}s_{\vec{x}}&0\\0&s_{\vec{x}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&-\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\+\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$

Normally you start from a known transformation and look for its properties.
You know $\mathfrak{t}$ and visualize its properties.
But you can reason backwards too.
The eigenvectors and eigenvalues are determined by the points $(\lambda_{A1},0)$ and $(\lambda_{A2},0)$ and $G(a,c)$.
So the set of all matrices with the same eigenvalues is the set of all circles containing the points  $(\lambda_{A1},0)$ and $(\lambda_{A2},0)$.

For completeness I add the definitions you need to construct an eigencircle:
$$f=\frac{\left(a+d\right)}{2}$$
$$g=\frac{\left(c-b\right)}{2}=-\frac{\left(b-c\right)}{2}$$
I explicitly state $-(b-c)$ since 'my' formulas are different from the ones in the articles of Englefield and Farr.
$$r^2=f^2+g^2$$
$$\det{\left(A\right)}=r^2-\rho^2$$
$$\rho^2=\left(\frac{a-d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\left(\lambda-f\right)^2+\left(\mu-g\right)^2-\rho^2=0 \ \ (1)$$
(1) is the equation of the eigencircle of the matrix $A$

If you need more detail, just ask it in a comment and I will add some more detail.
You can also visit [www.heavisidesdinner.com](https://www.heavisidesdinner.com).
 It shows the complete derivation and some geogebra examples.

There is a Geogebra example you can play with, at:
[Public Geogebra example showing eigencircles of $A$, $A^T$, $A^{-1}$](https://www.geogebra.org/m/xdk5jehk)

[[image: Eigencircle showing eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix <span class=]$A$ ">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUGoQ.png)